# Cross Domain Session Sharing Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, session

I have one Spring Boot application that handles requests on two domains (a.com, and b.com).  If the user is on a.com and clicks on a link to b.com, I would like to use the same session data from the original session.  Is this possible?

Comment: You may consider persisiting the session in redis or other persistance and abstract the session by user identity. Spring session or shiro can handle this situation.

Comment: @GuisongHe Thank you for your help.  I was able to solve my problem with your assistance. If you post an answer I will accept it as the correct answer.